# How to start chrome/chromium without controls and address bar, but with `example.com` page?

Tags: google-chrome

I want something like this:

```
 %Program files%\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe 
 http://example.com --no-controls --box-mode
```

or even just without the address bar (i.e. with controls).

[This picture](http://postimg.org/image/j0ieeboqz/) is close to what I'd like, although it has an address bar.

An alternative would be starting chrome like a popup window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start Chrome in "kiosk" mode from the command line or a shortcut with the `--kiosk` argument

Example:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --kiosk http://example.com"`